# Compactness of a subset of $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, weak-topology

Let $K \subset \ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ be a set defined as follows:
$$ K := \left\{x = (x_1, x_2, \dots) \in \ell^2(\mathbb{N}) \,|\, |x_n| \le \frac{1}{n}\right\}.$$
Since $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ is a reflexive space, we know that any sequence of $K$, being bounded, admits a converging subsequence by the Eberlein-Smulian theorem. Moreover, since $K$ is closed, the weakly converging subsequence has a limit in $K$, and thus $K$ is weakly sequentially compact.

Since $(\ell^2(\mathbb{N}))^*$ is separable, we know that $\overline{B(0,1)}$ is metrizable for the weak topology and hence $K$ is not only weakly sequentially compact but compact for the weak topology.

Is it compact for the strong topology as well?

Comment: If the "strong" topology is the norm topology then yes. (Given a sequence in $K$, a diagonal gives a pointwise-convergent subsequence, which then converges in norm by DCT.)

Comment: $K$ is homeomorphic to $\prod_{n=1}^\infty [0,1/n]$, which is compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is.
It is a standard (I mean "very common") argument in functional analysis, you can pick a sequence of points $(x_n)_n \in K^{\mathbb{N}}$ and proceed a Cantor's diagonal argument to extract a convergence subsequence. Then, it is just a matter of applying Lebesgue Dominated Convergence theorem to conclude convergece in $||.||_{\ell_2}$ as well.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, for a given sequence, the sequence given by the first component is in $[0,1]$ and thus admits a converging subsequence, same for the second component in $[0,1/2]$, and so on... Now, we take recursively subsequence of subsequence for each component and we are left we a converging subsequence in each component in addition to convergence in $\ell^2$?

Comment: Yes, this is the Cantor diagonal argument